# Execute UserControl readonly ICommand from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have a specialized `UserControl` to play media content called `PlayerView`.
The control has **its own commands** (**readonly**, not provided by client).

```
public partial class PlayerView
{
    public PlayerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                // Play some media: audio/video.
            });
    }

    ...

    #region PlayCommand property

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey PlayCommandPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
      "PlayCommand",
      typeof(ICommand),
      typeof(PlayerView),
      new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayCommandProperty = PlayCommandPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public ICommand PlayCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(PlayCommandProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(PlayCommandPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    ...
}
```

The play command of the control works fine from XAML:

```
<Controls:PlayerView x:Name="PlayerView" />
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=PlayerView, Path=PlayCommand, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Play" />
```

But currently, I am implemeting slideshow feature and I would like to execute the play command of the control from the **ViewModel**.

```
public class SlideshowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Stores collection of audio/video clips to be played by the PlayerView.

    // Assume that this ViewModel should invoke PlayerView PlayCommand.
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Stores a lot of stuff.

    public SlideshowViewModel Slideshow { get; }
}
```

[image: Class diagram]

The question is: how the **SlideshowViewModel can execute the PlayCommand of this control**? Is there a best practice?

Comment: "Is there a best practice?"  The best practice is to have this logic in your ViewModel

Comment: Of course, I know that. But I want to **simplify** usage of `PlayerControl`: client of the control should not know anything about how the control actually plays the audio/video and **even construct special ViewModel** for it.

Comment: So then you should have a general ViewModel with a virtual 'OnPlayClicked' method and each View should have a VM that implements that ViewModel but overrides that OnPlayCLicked method. This would be best practice and still simple.

Comment: have a look at this [article](http://matthamilton.net/commandbindings-with-mvvm) and this [one](http://codingcontext.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/commandbindings-in-mvvm/)

Comment: how are the `SlideshowViewModel` and `PlayerView` referencing one another?  Does either "know" about the other?

Comment: @jberger, maybe this is the way. But I don't know how to get reference to `PlayerView` in the `SlideshowViewModel`. Please see the updated diagram.

Comment: you may want to just put the `Play` command functionality into a different (non-control) class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your issue correctly, the ViewModel should contain the implementation of the Command, not the View. This would be a truer MVVM implementation, and then the VM can call that command from within itself, if necessary.

edit:

to answer your question,

```
public partial class PlayerView : IHaveAPlayCommand
{
public PlayerView()
{
      this.DataContext = new ViewModel(this);
}
}


public class ViewModel
{
      IHaveAPlayCommand view;
      public ViewModel(IHaveAPlayCommand view)
      {
           this.view = view
      }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already considered the option. But the control is **specialized** and client need not to know anything about its implementation. So, I want play command to be implemented inside the control.

Comment: I think it is certainly up for debate, but I believe that each view should have its own viewmodel. The view is just what you see; the logic is implemented in the VM.

Comment: However, to answer your question, when you set your datacontext to the viewmodel, you can pass in the instance of the view to that ViewModel, and have each view implement an interface that has your "Play" command. Then you'll have a reference to the view from within your VM.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I have `SlideshowViewModel`, the control doesn't have the knowledge of it, because it is an "external" ViewModel.
Could you please take a look at the ViewModels (the question has been updated)?

Comment: That seems like a nonconventional implementation, but if you are set on it being that way, then just pass the instance of the control into the mainViewModel, and from there, pass it to the SlideshowViewModel. Are you sure that Slideshowviewmodel shouldn't be derived from MAinViewModel?

Comment: I think he's looking for a similar implementation to `MediaCommands.Play`, where the command is defined and he wants to hook into it..?

Comment: @jberger, I want the `SlideshowViewModel` to call the `PlayCommand` of `PlayerView`. Please see the class diagram (the question has been updated).